# can isize and usize be different in rust?

Tags: rust

Can **isize and usize** be different?
Both of them can be used for memory size, index, offset.

Since **usize** is used for arrays why don't we just have usize

I am new to Rust so this might be a basic question.

Update: On a 32 bit system they are both 32 bit long and on a 64 bit system they are both 64 bit long. Irrespective of the sign.

Comment: One is signed and the other is unsigned... that... probably answers your question?

Comment: One doesn't make sense, the other is nice... ;)

Comment: What do you mean by *different*? They are two different types, so... yes?

Comment: @Shepmaster I am trying to understand why there are two type when we could just have one.

Comment: Do you understand why Rust has both `u32` and `i32`?

Comment: @Damian You mean only one because they have the same size ?!? well because they doesn't represent the same thing. look like you know some C++, well they are the same then [`ptrdiff_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/ptrdiff_t) (that I also don't like) and [`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/size_t)

Comment: @Stargateur I started reading the Rust Programming Language book and are amazed about the quality of the design! When reading this came though by head. Now I understand better.Thank you all!!

Comment: @Shepmaster I think you are trying tell me I am missing the point. I am mixing types and size of them.. but then again the size is the same for signed and unsigned types?

Comment: @Damian not trying to tell you anything yet; still figuring out where you are coming from. Do you understand why Rust has both signed and unsigned integer types to start with? Do you understand why Rust has a native-sized integer type?

Comment: Here is my current understanding. Rust uses [two’s complement representation](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html) for signed and unsigned integers which is used by most modern computers. 32 and 64 bit native platforms stores integers differently. I believe both it items lines up with the OS and CPU so it is efficient in time and space.

Comment: This is also known as [zero-cost abstractions](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2015/05/11/traits.html) ... as I said in my post I am new to Rust.

Answer (score 29):

On a 32 bit system, `isize` is the same as `i32` and `usize` is the same as `u32`. On a 64 bit system, `isize` is the same as `i64` and `usize` is the same as `u64`.

- `usize` cannot be negative and is generally used for memory addresses, positions, indices, lengths (or sizes!).
- `isize` *can* be negative, and is generally used for *offsets to* addresses, positions, indices, or lengths.

Comment: Has this changed? [`size_of` documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.size_of.html) explicitly says: "Furthermore, `usize` and `isize` have the same size."

Comment: @Thomas The line of documentation you mentioned was last updated [5 years ago](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/1529067a046b079c1348ead39199e9c491a5f472), perhaps coincidentally, a few weeks after I wrote this answer.

As it happens, my answer is based on an incorrect understanding of CHERI. The sizes of `usize` and `isize` would still be 64bits when targetting the CHERI architecture,  however pointers, e.g. `*const T` would be 128 bits! I think that actually makes it practically untenable for Rust to target CHERI because too much existing unsafe code would have unsound assumptions.

Comment: I am deleting that section of my answer since, if I corrected it, it would no longer be interesting here :)

Answer (score 5):

**isize** is architecture-based(e.g. 32bit/64bit) **signed**(negative/0/positive) integer type.

See [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.isize.html):

> Primitive Type isize
>
> The pointer-sized signed integer type.
>
> See also the std::isize module.
>
> The size of this primitive is how many bytes it takes to reference any
>   location in memory. For example, on a 32 bit target, this is 4 bytes
>   and on a 64 bit target, this is 8 bytes.

**usize** is architecture-based(e.g. 32bit/64bit) **unsigned**(0/positive) integer type.

See [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.usize.html):

> Primitive Type usize
>
> The pointer-sized unsigned integer type.
>
> See also the std::usize module.
>
> The size of this primitive is how many bytes it takes to reference any
>   location in memory. For example, on a 32 bit target, this is 4 bytes
>   and on a 64 bit target, this is 8 bytes.