# Why do we have arch/ usize / isize types in rust?

Tags: rust

Having read "the book", some SO posts (like this one: [can isize and usize be different in rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55506647/can-isize-and-usize-be-different-in-rust)), I am still uncertain if I understand `usize` and `isize`.

As I understand it, `usize` is the largest amount of contiguous space (in memory) that any individual object could be provided *within your architecture*. As such, since arrays are contiguously allocated, we should use `usize` when creating an index. Are there other strong/primary use-cases of this type?

That said, I see limited value in `isize`. Is this for negative indexing, to reach the end of some array? Does rust support this? (Aka, idx of `-1` is the end of an array, `-2` is the second to last index, etc.?) But under what circumstances is this useful? Why would I use this instead of a `usize`? Even with an offset, given some starting address, `usize` seems to be the ideal solution?

Comment: The title of the other question is different, but the answers cover your questions

Comment: @vallentin I read through that, which assisted my understanding (certainly), though it still left me questions w.r.t `isize`, and I feel uncertain if I have arrived at the correct understanding w/ `usize`. That uncertainty is what had originally lead me to asking this question. I suspect I am gesticulating in the correct direction, but I feel I need a stronger confirmation, or that I am missing something.

Comment: Which question wasn't answered? In short, if `usize` represents a pointer, then say you want to offset it by `-2`, how would you do that with `usize`? Well, you wouldn't you'd use `isize`. We can't remove `isize` and replace it with `i64`, because what if a platform defines `isize` as `i32` and not `i64`?

Comment: @vallentin I see the flaw in my thinking. Though, would you be able to provide a concrete example of a scenario that would necessitate a negative offset? Maybe I am being too simple in my consideration of addresses?

Comment: I have never programmed using Rust but am a grey beard who has programmed on many architectures considered unusual today. Such as a CDC Cyber 170 with a 60 bit word length, A Honeywell minicomputer (I don't recall the model) with a 36 bit word length, and a Harris H100 and H500 with a 24 bit word length. Historically it is not unusual for architectures to have different pointer and int sizes. Google "ilp64 vs lp64" to get just a tiny sense of the problem.

Comment: @CaffeineDependent It's often not about if something is necessarily required, but if it might make something easier to read/work with (If you want to have the relation between two `usize` you can use either one `isize` or two variables, one describing the distance and one the direction). You could also argue if `for` , `while` and `loop` are all required.